# Reshape error when building Keras model: Dimension size must be evenly divisible by 128000 but is 524288

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Here's the link to the code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MHWYPSEJym2xpFeLNEaOwlms8i4CWPL_?usp=sharing

I'm making a model that can take a spectrogram image from an audio file, and return what is being said in the audio. I'm using the [speechocean 762 dataset](https://github.com/jimbozhang/speechocean762.git). I'm trying to implement a similar model found here: https://keras.io/examples/audio/ctc_asr/#model

When training the model, it gives the following error:
Dimension size must be evenly divisible by 128000 but is 524288 for '{{node DeepSpeech_2/expand_dim/Reshape}} = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32](IteratorGetNext, DeepSpeech_2/expand_dim/Reshape/shape)' with input shapes: [32,16384], [4] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1](https://github.com/jimbozhang/speechocean762.git) = [32,?,4000,1].

I think it's a dimensionality problem, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: I looked at your data shape and either I'm missing something or it is wrong. `X_train` has shape `(4000, 16384)`, so 4000 samples with 16384 features. You then reshape this to `(16384, 1)`, which is one dimension too low for `Conv2D`. What data shape do you expect for your data? You set the kernel size to `(11, 41)`, so you have to reshape the data more than to add one more `(,1)` dimension. To solve the error message in your question, I think the message you get comes from the `None` in your shape tuples (the batch dimension is excluded in the shape tuples).

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, you don't save the StandardScaler you use to scale `X_train`. Remember to use the same scaler for your training and test sets, fit on the training set.